# Print audio file size while recording android

Tags: android, audio-recording, filesize

I have implemented audio recording in my app. I want to print size of the audio recording while it is recording , so that i can know file size while it is recording and stop it manually when it reaches a certain size. I have uses a textview to display file size.

Comment: and what is the problem? you don't know how to get the size of the file?

Comment: I know how to get the size of file, but it is only printing size once recording is started , not updating file size

Comment: If you don't need exactly byte to byte matching of max size, you can check for the file size periodically. If you need it exactly match, then you can pre-calculate max recording length in seconds, as you record audio with a fixed bit-rate, etc.